# Displaying entires by year from a custom date field

Tags: entries, datetime, routing

I have a date field (date) in my entry and I wish to get all entries of a specified year.  Can’t figure it out at all.  Here’s what I have now, to sort them by that field:

```
craft.entries.section('evenements').order('date desc')
```

My "year" is passed to the page through routing and is named "year".  I can get that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I finally found an answer to it

year being my param

date being my custom date field

```
{% set dateParam = 'and, >= ' ~ year ~ '-01-01, < ' ~ (year + 1) ~ '-01-01' %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('evenements').order('date desc').date(dateParam) %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Curiously, does that work? I would think you'd need to pass an array into that param, like this:


`{% set dateParam = ['and', '>= ' ~ year, '< ' ~ (year + 1)] %}`

Comment: Well, it does work like I wrote it.  But, it works the way you did it too.  I get the exact same results both ways. Interesting...  Keeping your way in my code though, it is definitely cleaner.

Comment: Cool. Where did you find the example/inspiration for feeding a string into the date param?

Comment: p.s. I double-checked with Brad. He confirmed that date parameters accept a string or an array by design: _DateFieldType_'s `modifyElementsQuery` calls `DbHelper::parseDateParam()` and the first thing that does is convert the value to an array if it's not one: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/helpers/DbHelper.php#L557 — Pretty cool!

Comment: I found it on another question here somewhere.  I can't remember how I found it though. I repurposed the answer to my situation and it worked.